# Using malloc in C to make sure that user enter certain digits

Tags: c, string, integer, malloc, atoi

So I want to write a program to check if user enter. Say requirement is 4 digits number, if user enters 5 then program keeps asking user to renter exactly 4 digit number.

I got the working code like this: basically use `scanf` to read in a string value, then use `strlen` to count number of digits.  If user enters the correct digit, then I use `atoi` to convert that string into an `int`, which I will use for later. 
Say requirement is 4 digit number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int digit, mynumber;        
    int digit = 5;
    char str[5]; 

    /* Checking if enter the correct digit */
    do {
        printf("Enter a %d digit number\n", digit);
        scanf("%s", &str);
        if (strlen(str) != digit) {
            printf("You entered %d digits. Try again \n", strlen(str));
        } else { 
            printf("You entered %d digits. \n", strlen(str)); 
            printf("Converting string to num.....\n"); 
            mynumber = atoi(str); 
            printf("The number is %d\n", mynumber); 
        } 
    } while (strlen(str) != digit);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to modify this a bit. Instead of doing `char str[5]` for 5 digit string. I want to try a dynamic array.

So in place of char `str[5]`, I do this:

```
char *str;
str = malloc(sizeof(char) * digit);
```

Running this through the code gives seg fault. Can anyone help me with this?

This is the complete code with the issue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int mynumber;
    int digit = 5;
    char *str;
    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * digit);

    /* Checking if enter the correct digit */
    do {
        printf("Enter a %d digit number\n", digit);
        scanf("%s", &str);
        if (strlen(str) != digit) {
            printf("You entered %d digits. Try again \n", strlen(str));
        } else {
            printf("You entered %d digits. \n", strlen(str));
            printf("Converting string to num.....\n");
            mynumber = atoi(str);
            printf("The number is %d\n", mynumber);
        }
    } while (strlen(str) != digit);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that has the issue? I suspect you are passing the address of `str` to `scanf` but without the code that's just a guess.

Comment: You need `malloc(digit+1)`. One extra byte is needed for the string NUL terminator.

Comment: I just added the complete code that gives issue.

Comment: And you need `scanf("%s", str);` No `&` as `str` is already a pointer.

Comment: `char str[5];  ... scanf("%s", &str);` should use `scanf("%4s", str);`. If code needs to read more than 4 characters, use a bigger buffer.

Comment: malloc(digit+1) and just use str in scanf solve my problem.  Thank you !

Comment: Any code that uses `scanf("%s", ...` (`"%s"` without a width limit) should fail a code review.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use the formatted input function `scanf` to take your input as a string, `scanf` is full of a number of pitfalls that can leave stray characters in your input stream (`stdin`) depending on whether a *matching-failure* occurs. It also has the limitation using the `"%s"` *conversion specifier* of only reading up to the first *whitespace*. If your user slips and enters `"123 45"`, you read `"123"`, your tests fail, and `"45"` are left in `stdin` unread, just waiting to bite you on  your next attempted read unless you manually empty `stdin`.

Further, if you are using `"%s"` without the *field-width* modifier -- you might as well be using `gets()` as `scanf` will happily read an unlimited number of characters into your 5 or 6 character array, writing beyond your array bounds invoking *Undefined Behavior*.

A more sound approach is the provide a character buffer large enough to handle whatever the user may enter. (*don't Skimp on buffer size*). The read an entire line at a time with `fgets()`, which with a sufficient sized buffer ensure the entire line is consumed eliminating the chance for characters to remain unread in `stdin`. The only caveat with `fgets` (and every *line-oriented* input function like POSIX `getline`) is the `'\n'` is also read and included in the buffer filled. You simply trim the `'\n'` from the end using `strcspn()` as a convenient method obtaining the number of characters entered at the same time.

(**note:** you can forego trimming the `'\n'` if you adjust your tests to include the `'\n'` in the length you validate against since the conversion to `int` will ignore the trailing `'\n'`)

Your logic is lacking one other needed check. What if the user enters `"123a5"`? All 5 characters were entered, but they were not all digits. `atoi()` has no error reporting capability and will happily convert the string to `123` silently without providing any indication that additional characters remain. You have two-options, either use `strtol` for the conversion and validate no characters remain, or simply loop over the characters in your string checking each with `isdigit()` to ensure all digits were entered.

Putting that altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NDIGITS     5   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC     1024

int main (void) {

    int mynumber;
    size_t digit = NDIGITS;        
    char buf[MAXC];                         /* buffer to hold MAXC chars */

    /* infinite loop until valid string entered, or manual EOF generated */
    for (;;) {
        size_t len;
        printf("\nEnter a %zu digit number: ", digit);  /* prompt */
        if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {          /* read entire line */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
            break;
        }
        buf[(len = strcspn(buf, "\n"))] = 0;            /* trim \n, get len */
        if (len != digit) {                             /* validate length */
            fprintf(stderr, "  error: %zu characters.\n", len);
            continue;
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {              /* validate all digits */
            if (!isdigit(buf[i])) {
                fprintf (stderr, "  error: buf[%zu] is non-digit '%c'.\n",
                        i, buf[i]);
                goto getnext;
            }
        }
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &mynumber) == 1) {   /* validate converstion */
            printf ("you entered %zu digits, mynumber = %d\n", len, mynumber);
            break;      /* all criteria met, break loop */
        }
        getnext:; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Whenever you write an input routine, go try and break it. Validate it does what you need it to do and catches the cases you want to protect against (and there will still be more validations you can add). Here, it covers most anticipated abuses:

```
$ ./bin/only5digits

Enter a 5 digit number: no
  error: 2 characters.

Enter a 5 digit number: 123a5
  error: buf[3] is non-digit 'a'.

Enter a 5 digit number: 123 45
  error: 6 characters.

Enter a 5 digit number: ;alsdhif aij;ioj34 ;alfj a!%#$%$ ("cat steps on keyboard...")
  error: 61 characters.

Enter a 5 digit number: 1234
  error: 4 characters.

Enter a 5 digit number: 123456
  error: 6 characters.

Enter a 5 digit number: 12345
you entered 5 digits, mynumber = 12345
```

User cancels input with <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux (or <kbd>ctrl+z</kbd> on windows) generating a manual `EOF`:

```
$ ./bin/only5digits

Enter a 5 digit number: (user canceled input)
```

(**note:** you can add additional checks to see if 1024 or more characters were input -- that is left to you)

This is a slightly different approach to reading input, but from a general rule standpoint, when taking user input, if you ensure you consume an entire line of input, you avoid many of the pitfalls associated with using `scanf` for that purpose.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have an array of 5 bytes. If the user enters more than 4 digits, `scanf` will happily overflow the array and corrupt the memory. It will corrupt the memory in both cases, as an array and as a `malloc`. However, not every memory corruption causes a crash.

So, you need to limit the number of bytes the `scanf` can read. The way to do it is to use `%4s` in the format string.

However, in this case you will not be able to detect when the user enters more than 4 digits. You would need at least 1 more byte: `str[6]` and `%5s`;

I suggest, instead of using `scanf`, use `getchar`. It would allow you to read character by character and count them on the way.